# odd syntax with question mark in variable declaration

Tags: javascript

I've been tasked with working on some code that I didn't write, but there is a line in this code that I just don't understand.

```
var headerHeight = window.innerWidth > 1920 ? $('.bottom-header').outerHeight() + $('.bottom-fixed-selector').outerHeight() : 0;
```

what I do understand is that the question mark is a conditional operator. I had no idea a conditional operator could be used within a variable declaration, however. Is there an alternative way to write this that is easier for me to understand?

Comment: It's actually called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Pretty much similar to an `if` statement.

Comment: This belongs to the  [MDN: Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: `let headerHeight = 0; if (window.innerWidth > 1920) { headerHeight = $('.bottom-header').outerHeight() + $('.bottom-fixed-selector').outerHeight() }`

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate (at least with the one linked to), OP is asking for an equivalent to the code he posted. In any case, if OP is reading. This is the equivalent: https://pastebin.com/r7BXh0p5

Comment: You can replace it with **If..Else** condition like below

    var headerHeight = 0;
    if(window.innerWidth > 1920){
        headerHeight = $('.bottom-header').outerHeight() + $('.bottom-fixed-selector').outerHeight();
    }

BTW that one is ternary operator not conditional operator.